# How to convert a string "yyyy-MM-ddZ" to a date time with .net?

Tags: .net, datetime, timezone

I am having problems converting a string in the format "yyyy-MM-ddZ" using VB.net.

For example I have the string "2007-10-21Z".

Using CDate or TryParse it comes out to 10/20/2007 instead of 10/21/2007.

I'm not understanding how the Z affects the date string so that when it is parsed it results in the day before.

From what I understand Z specifies the zero timezone.  But the date string has no time information.  How does this work?

Comment: Thanks.  I not only learned why the date became a date before but how to make it so I get the date without the timezone shift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

DateTime.ParseExact("2007-10-21Z", "yyyy-MM-ddZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: I am fairly sure that the CUltureInfo.InvariantCulture is the key.

Answer (score 8):

It's interpreting the date as midnight Zulu (GMT) time and then converting it back to your local time zone. If you're in the States that would be between 3:00PM to 7:00 PM in the previous day.

Answer (score 4):

Adding "Z" to the date specifies that time is [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC).  When you CDate of TryParse the date, it is converting it to local time.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's interesting.  I try in C# DateTime.Parse("2008-10-31").ToString(); and the result is "10/30/2008 5:00:00 PM".

I can't wait for an answer!

Comment: Surely you meant to type DateTime.Parse("2008-10-31Z")? (The "Z" is missing in your post). Otherwise your result doesn't make sense.